# Local Ubuntu Mirror NOT working?

Tags: server, apt, mirrors

I recently migrated to Ubuntu from Win 8.1 (Used to try Ubuntu sometime back but went away..).

After my initial install, the default server (mirror) selected for my Sri Lanka location was http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu/. As of last night, the same is NOT working and the secondary mirror http:/archieve.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu was also down.

(Down = Returning 404 errors)

But as per the below link the LEARN mirror is still up - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.learn.ac.lk-archive

Can someone please explain this to me?

My internet connectivity is working fine as I'm able to download from the main server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are finding that BOTH above-mentioned mirrors are still showing in the mirror list after running `apt-get update` from main servers,
you can always edit the `sources.list` using your favorite text editor, in my case `nano`. ;-)

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And replace the lines:

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

With the URL of your preferred server. You can find the list of mirrors here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

However, please make sure to navigate to the URL before using it as your preferred mirror, as there are instances where the domains are expired.

*Once again thanks Ron for the pointers! :-D*

Answer (score 4):

There is no [http:/archieve.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu](http://http:/archieve.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu) mirror for Sri Lanka in the list.

[image]

If you look at [LEARN](http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu/releases/) mirror, you can see that it is not maintained very well. Instead of acting as a package repository, that mirror just redirect you to the [image download](http://mirror.learn.ac.lk/ubuntu/releases/vivid/) page of Ubuntu!

I suggest you use the main repo or the one for India.

Comment: Dear Ron,

Thanks a lot for the reply and clarification on LEARN.

H/e when trying to set the mirror through the GUI , the LEARN mirror & SCHOOLNET mirrors both popup under Sri Lanka .

And when I let the GUI tool to select the BEST mirror , It automatically picks the SCHOOLNET mirror.

Anyways , I'm thinking of using the main server OR a closer server with a good link as my mirror.

Comment: Use the main server or the next closest one. Also since you are a new user, If the above post helped you, do  not forget to mark it as the answer to your question ;)

Comment: Dear Ron,

Sure will do,

If it's not too much trouble can you tell me why below mentioned mirror is not showing up on gui "Software & Updates" ??

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com-archive

Comment: There are specific requirements that must be met to become a country mirror. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors

Comment: Dear Ron,

Unfortunately still BOTH the above mentioned mirrors are shown in my mirror list (GUI).

H/e found a workaround :

Manually edited the "source.list" file using "sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list"
 
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.cloud.id-archive

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue when updating for packages.Then I changed my local mirror to http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/ubuntu and now it's ok.

Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Ubuntu Software tab - > select a Indian server to Download from drop down.

then do a apt-get update on Terminal.

Problem sloved.
ps: it's really bad that Lankan mirror is not working.

Comment: Heyy... Tks for the reply. But the Indian servers too are a bit slow to update their rep from the main rep. So I ultimately settled for an Indonesian mirror.... It's lightening fast & always up to date  :D