# I get "Cannot initiate the connection to tr.archive.ubuntu.com:80" when trying to update Ubuntu 20.04. Is tr.archive.ubuntu.com down?

Tags: 20.04, updates

Ubuntu update gives following error:

```
Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgres...
Cannot initiate the connection to tr.archive.ubuntu.com:80 - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to tr.archive.ubuntu.com:80 connect (101: Network is unreachable)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I also tried `sudo apt-get update` but no results. I tried to send `ping` to `tr.archive.ubuntu.com`, but it was successful.

Comment: You can use another mirror.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is my Ubuntu mirror down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162937/is-my-ubuntu-mirror-down)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local Ubuntu Mirror NOT working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670239/local-ubuntu-mirror-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You experienced this because archive.ubuntu.com experienced a major outage today between Jan 13, 2023 11:31 AM UTC and Jan 13, 2023 11:46 PM UTC. See [incident report](https://status.canonical.com/#/incident/KNms6QK9ewuzz-7xUsPsNylV20jEt5kyKsd8A-3ptQFdhagDnjfaXXVpElWI5MToWkxoAA9XuP4NaRBzB2kxAQ==) by Canonical for more details.

The incident has now been resolved, so you should be able to pull packages successfully now.